# Lookup multiple values from one cell

Tags: google-sheets

Trying to obtain desired output shown in `E:G` from a data show in `A:C`. I can write a formula

```
JOIN(", ", FILTER($B$2:$B,$C$2:$C=E2,$A$2:$A=F2))
```

If there would be a single value in `F2` I could get comma-separated output items from column B. But I need to do that for more than one value in `F2` cell and get the output shown in column G. How to write a formula that can generate column G as desired?

Any help is welcome.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're happy with formula dragging down each cell, as per your example in cell `F2`, then `G2` could be:

`=join(",",unique(filter({$A:$A&"("&$B:$B&")"},$C:$C=$E2)))`

[image]

There are more complex formula to do the calcs with an `arrayformula`.

Within the `filter`, there are `{}` brackets that are used to build an array of data. The array consists of `Col A` then `(` then `Col B` then `)`.

It then works the same way as per your example in cell `F2`. The `filter` finds each row of the array where Col C matches the value in Col E. `Unique` and `join` get the results the same way.

When you drag down the formula, `textjoin` might be more helpful in ignoring empty cells than `join`.

Use this in cell `F2`:

`=textjoin(",",true,filter(A:A,C:C=E2))`

this in cell `G2`:

`=textjoin(",",true,unique(filter(if($A:$A<>"",{$A:$A&"("&$B:$B&")"},),$C:$C=$E2)))`

**Using arrays in Google Sheets**

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276/using-arrays-in-google-sheets?hl=en-GB

Comment: yes. It worked. I am new to this and thanks for indtroducing it to me. Can you give me some references where I can find more such stuffs?

Comment: one more thing, can we get G-4(8, 9) in place of G(8), G(9)? means same group items in single bracket.